# Is overheating actually a risk for hardware, with all the internal safeguards now present?

Tags: temperature, overheating

Most computers now have safety things that turn them off if they get too hot (for example, according to the Intel website, my Intel T4400's T Junction is 105 degrees C).

With most internal safeguards most computers just shut off before they get too hot.

Thus, why is overheating considered to be so bad, when they turn off anyway before any real damage can be done?

Comment: Because when it comes to ICB "heat kills".  There are a ton of ICB on a motherboard and if the CPU is overheating those other ICB are also likely overheating.  Even if they are not reaching their thermal limits the heat itself will eventually lead to their early failure.

Comment: Of course extreme colds also kills ICBs which is the reason in a military application specific designs are used.  Typically this involves using different types of metal instead of using what normally might be used.  **This topic itself is really big far to big to be explained in a couple hundred words.**

Comment: Maybe you might want to clarify what you mean by "now", given that the example hardware component you gave (Intel T4400) is 4+ years old.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Some specific components shut off or throttle, such as the CPU, GPU, and some hard drives. But many other critical components typically don't, such as RAM, VRMs, and so on.

Comment: But don't the CPU and GPUs get the hottest first, and heat up the fastest? Therefore I assume that the computer would shut off before the RAM and VRM etc overheated...

Comment: @GeorgeH - Sure the computer might shutdown.  That doesn't stop the current temperatures from causing harm to the other ICBs.

Comment: @GeorgeH You'd be surprised how hot VRMs can get. At least CPUs and GPUs have beefy heatsinks and fans to cool them.

Comment: @GeorgeH Not always, because those components can throttle when they get hot. With proper cooling, that should be the way it works. But without proper cooling, all bets are off.